# How to get email from Google Python SDK oauth2?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

This seems like a dumb question but I literally can't find it anywhere in the google sdk documentation.

How do I get the email address (`xxxxx@gmail.com`) from the user account that just authorized me offline access to one of the Google APIs?

```
import httplib2
import datetime  

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client


json_credentials_as_string = "..."

credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(json_credentials_as_string)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http_auth)

# ...?
```

List of services is [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/) but no mention of anything to actually get the user's information.

[This shows how to get the primary calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) (using the 'primary' calendarId), which is likely their account email, but I'm not sure that it has to be? If someone changed their primary calendar, it seems like that may not return their google email id (xxxx@gmail.com), which is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Include `email` in your list of OAuth 2.0 scopes. Then try:

```
print 'Authenticated as: %s' % credentials.id_token[u'email']
```

Comment: What is the scope url for that?

Comment: Don't use a URL, just use the literal string "email".

Comment: where is this in the documentation?